# Bind different model name with jackson

Tags: angular, spring, jackson

Is it a way with Jackson annotation to bind Userd on my front with User in my back?

I have a model in my Angular project :

```
export class UserD {
  email: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  entity: Entities;
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

I have a model in my Spring boot project :

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    Entity entity;
    private Boolean isActive;
```

With my form who send in a body a owner object and a stage,  i cant bind both model because of the class names.

my form is a type of

```
public class Bor {
    private String stage;
    private User owner;
```

i try JsonProperty with no success

Comment: `JsonProperty` should work. Are you definitely using the correct annotation? It should be `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;` for all recent versions of Jackson.

Comment: yes i use the correct one, should i use JsonProperty on Bor class? like @JsonProperty("userD) above User owner?

Comment: Yes, the annotation should be just before the `owner` field.

Comment: that what i did

Comment: Could you show `JSON` payload which you try to deserialise?

Comment: owner: {email: "", firstname: "qaqaqa", lastname: "", entities: null}
stage: "2". from the angular form

Comment: i am trying with JsonTypeInfo but with no succes for now

Comment: I might found why its not working, this is not a type issue here, by changing  in spring boot User by UserD, its working (even thos if  i switch on angular name UserD by User). i think its trying to call my custom deserializer.